# How to set absolute position of GLMeshItem in 3D pyqtgraph implementation

Tags: python, opengl, pyqtgraph

I am building a visualizer for some data and want to use 3D spheres plotted in pyqtgraphs 3D OpenGL components to represent targets identified within the data provided.

I am able to generate the spheres and move them using `GLMeshItem.translate()` commands, however I am not able to find a convenient way of setting coordinates of the sphere without first getting the current position of said spheres through a call to .transform() and then generating a translate command from it's current position to the new absolute coordinates I would like it to be moved to.  It may be that that is the only way to accomplish this, I just suspect there is a more direct set the mesh items absolute coordinates that I just can't seem to identify.

The following code shows a basic framework for what I am doing, and also the current method I am using to move the sphere.

```py
from pyqtgraph.Qt import QtCore, QtGui
import pyqtgraph as pg
import pyqtgraph.opengl as gl
import numpy as np

app = QtGui.QApplication([])
w = gl.GLViewWidget()
w.showMaximized()
w.setWindowTitle('pyqtgraph example: GLMeshItem')
w.setCameraPosition(distance=40)

g = gl.GLGridItem()
g.scale(2,2,1)
w.addItem(g)

verts = np.array([
    [0, 0, 0],
    [2, 0, 0],
    [1, 2, 0],
    [1, 1, 1],
])
faces = np.array([
    [0, 1, 2],
    [0, 1, 3],
    [0, 2, 3],
    [1, 2, 3]
])
colors = np.array([
    [1, 0, 0, 0.3],
    [0, 1, 0, 0.3],
    [0, 0, 1, 0.3],
    [1, 1, 0, 0.3]
])


md = gl.MeshData.sphere(rows=4, cols=4)

colors = np.ones((md.faceCount(), 4), dtype=float)
colors[::2,0] = 0
colors[:,1] = np.linspace(0, 1, colors.shape[0])
md.setFaceColors(colors)
m3 = gl.GLMeshItem(meshdata=md, smooth=False)#, shader='balloon')
w.addItem(m3)

target = gl.MeshData.sphere(4,4,10)
targetMI = gl.GLMeshItem(meshdata = target, drawFaces = True,smooth = False)
w.addItem(targetMI)
while(1):
    targetMI.translate(0.1,0,0)
    app.processEvents()



## Start Qt event loop unless running in interactive mode.
if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    if (sys.flags.interactive != 1) or not hasattr(QtCore, 'PYQT_VERSION'):
        QtGui.QApplication.instance().exec_()
```

As can be seen in this example.  translate works fine for moving relative to the current position.  I am just curious as to whether there is a method for doing an absolute position move on the `GLMeshItem` (in this case `targetMI`) such that I could make it move to a coordinate without having to first get the transform and then calculating the translate required to move to the desired coordinates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An option is to reset the item’s transform to an [identity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Identity_matrix) transformation by [`resetTransform()`](http://www.pyqtgraph.org/documentation/3dgraphics/glgraphicsitem.html), before you set the absolute position by `translate()`. e.g:

```py
targetMI.resetTransform()
targetMI.translate(10, 0, 0)
```

Comment: This solves the problem perfectly and makes sense.  Thank you for both the solution as well as the link describing the underlying principal.  Cheers!